# SSH into Windows WSL2 - Access Denied

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, wsl2

I want to ssh into WSL2 running on Windows 11 using win32-openSSH 8.1.

I tried to change the default shell of openSSH to bash.exe (or ubuntu.exe) using

`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`. However, the ssh client always receives "Access Denied."

Using PowerShell as the default openSSH shell works, but I also get the "Access Denied" as soon as I try to run `wsl` within the ssh Powershell.

Surprisingly, when I execute `wsl` with the same user locally, I have no issues and can launch the Linux Distribution.

Comment: When you *"execute `wsl` with the same user locally"*, how are you starting it?  From PowerShell, the Start Menu, Windows Terminal, etc.?  Also, does it display a UAC prompt when you run it?  I'm assuming "no", but just want to double-check.

Comment: I started it from Windows Terminal (using the old and the new Powershell). I don't see any UAC prompt both locally and through ssh.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue: Apparently, the issue is known by the WSL team: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/store-release-notes

Comment: Okay, it looks like that is a bug specifically with the *Preview* WSL in the Microsoft Store.  Is that what you are running?